# CodenameOne Install Error for iOS

Tags: codenameone

Once I finished building my app for iOS on the codename website, I tried downloading it onto my iPhone but whenever I click install an error message pops up saying

> "Cannot connect to codename-one.appspot.com"

Comment: Can you update your question with the full error message you are getting? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device has a valid internet connection and that the browser can reach https://codename-one.appspot.com/

If you are behind a firewall you might need to configure your device to use a VPN or go around said firewall.